# The structure of reference type in detail

Tags: c#

I know a reference type object is comprised of two parts: a reference to the object, which is essentially a pointer holds the address of the real object, and the object itself that resides on the heap, which might be moved by the GC. The object itself, in turn, consists of two parts: the instance data part (fields) and the metadata part.

I've read numerous pages on the web talking about the storage model of reference type, but none of them gives specific description about how is the metadata part organized. I only learned that it occupied 8 bytes on 32-bit system (which could be observed via profiling), and 4 bytes out of it holds a pointer points to the vtable, but what about the extra 4 bytes? GC marks? built-in attributes? Does anyone know it in detail? I know it's implementation specific, I'm just dying to know how is it actually bit-for-bit organized. For instance, Boehm GC only need a bit as mark, why on earth does CLR need 4 bytes?

--->8----

See the link provided by Damian in the comments! That's the answer I've been looking for.

Comment: Pretty decent article from 2005 - [Drill Into .NET Framework Internals to See How the CLR Creates Runtime Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx#S7)

Comment: (And, of course, your first sentence is a bit off - you shouldn't think of the reference as being "part" of a reference type object, since of course, there can be multiple references to the same object)

Comment: @leppie Yes I could, but it's a mound of code, I just don't know where to look

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thank you very much! It's indeed a very decent article, I only wish I had found it sooner, it's definitely a must-read for all C# programmers :)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever But a reference of a reference type object is mandatory, without reference the object would be collected by the GC, English is not my native tongue, I just don't know how to phrase it more clearly.

Comment: I might add that "Pro .NET Performance" from Sasha Goldshtein has an excellent chapter about type internals (Chapter 3 Type Internals).